# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte while installing aldryn-newsblog

Tags: django, encoding, django-cms, cyrillic

I'm developing a web page using Python 2.7, Django 1.7, Django-CMS 3.1.3. I've decided to install `aldryn-newsblog`. But while installing I received an error message `...UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...`
As I found out it was because of Cyrillic in paths (I use Russian version of OS).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved after I installed an `libxslt1-dev` package for debian-based systems: `apt-get install libxslt1-dev`.

Hope this information will be useful.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Stack says, that I can't do that for a 2 days :(